# What does rx_csum_offload_errors mean?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, ethernet, nic, ethtool

I see too many rx_csum_offload_errors on ethtool output and it constantly increases. What is the reason of these errors and how can I fix it?

```
# ethtool -S enp12s0f0 | grep error
     rx_errors: 0
     tx_errors: 0
     rx_over_errors: 0
     rx_crc_errors: 0
     rx_frame_errors: 0
     rx_fifo_errors: 0
     rx_missed_errors: 0
     tx_aborted_errors: 0
     tx_carrier_errors: 0
     tx_fifo_errors: 0
     tx_heartbeat_errors: 0
     rx_long_length_errors: 0
     rx_short_length_errors: 0
     rx_csum_offload_errors: 4421920
```

Answer (score 0):

rx_csum_offload_errors indicates packets are coming with bad checksums, from where we don’t know. Its not good & it can lead to corruption. I would say the cables/ports/NICs/SFPs has to be checked.